# Using GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext to send message to client in case of different projects doesn't work

Tags: signalr-hub

Basically I have two different projects
1) ChatHub and HubCommon is SignalR Hub project (hosted in IIS)
2) And Web API project with GET and POST method (hosted in IIS)
I'm using GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext  to get the hubcontext and than broadcast the message to all clients.Im unable to send message to clients
please suggest alternative way to access the SignalR Hub methods from different project.

The possible options I tried:-
1) using GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext [It isn't working]
2) Implement WebAPI project as SignalR .Net Client [It works but don't want to use this approach]

Please suggest any other approach to achieve this ??

```
Here is my code for reference:-

    //This is SignalR Hub project
        public class ChatHub : Hub
                            {
        //This is my HUB class which sends message using assetid
                                public void Send(string name, string message, string assetid)
                                {
                                    //Send message to specific client based on Asset ID
                                   Clients.Group(assetid).broadcastMessage(name, message);
                                }

                                public override Task OnConnected()
                                {
                                    //Clients.All.reportConnections("A new client connection " + Context.ConnectionId);

                                    //Retrieve the assetid from the query string
                                    var assetid = Context.QueryString["assetid"];

                                    //Single-user groups approach- Create a group for each user using AssetID
                                    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, assetid);
                                    return base.OnConnected();
                                }           
                        }


                         public class HubCommon
                            {
                                           // This class belongs to my ChatHub Project but exposed to my WebAPI project
                                public void SendToHub(string name, string message, string assetid)
                                {

                                     IHubContext _hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
         //This ideally broadcast the message to all the clients but it my case it doesn't
_hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name,message);
 }
}               
    //This is WEP API Project
            //This is my Web API POST method which sends message to the all clients
    //associated to Hub                   
                  public string Post([FromBody]Item data)
                        {

                            string message= data.Data[0].Value;

                            Instantiate HubCommon and invoke the SendToHub method
                            HubCommon hubcommon = new HubCommon();
                            hubcommon.SendToHub(Item.datatype, message,Item.assetid);

                            //Test response code
                            return data.datatype;
                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multi-project scenarios, use the following

```
var _hubContext = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<ChatHub>();

  //This broadcasts the message to all the clients 
 _hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name,message);
```

Comment: Yes Samuel, this should mostly work will try this and update.